# How to change the font size of the whole abstract in the article class

Tags: fontsize, abstract, article

I am using the following to generate an article with 12pt and 1.5 linespread:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\linespread{1.5} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{abstract} 
Abstract 
\end{abstract} 
\end{document}
```

Of course the abstract appears to have a smaller font size than 12. How can I make all fonts in my article to be 12pt?

Comment: You could use `\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont` at the beginning of the document. You can also use other sizes for the `14pt` (leading) but it should be larger than the `12pt`. The leading determines the distance between subsequent lines (assuming they are not stretched).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have several options.

- Add `\normalsize` right at the beginning of the abstract
- Patch the `abstract` environment by »[etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)«.
- Renew the `abstract` environment by taking its original code from the `article` class and doing the modifications by hand.

The first option is the shortest.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    \normalsize
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}
```

The next option is a bit longer.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\patchcmd{\abstract}{\small}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}

  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The last option is a much longer and makes the code unclear.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
%        \small  % this causes the smaller font size
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}

  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

All you have to do is to choose your favorite method.

Comment: Or just issue `\normalsize` inside the `abstract` environment. That would by my option 0, since it's a one-time use change. :)

Comment: Thank you Werner! Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it! However also thank you Thorsten, your methods worked fine but are much longer...

Comment: @C.Colden: I incorporated that option into my answer.

Comment: There is one another way, by making abstract a section: `\section*{Abstract}`

Comment: `\normalsize` did not work on overleaf in 2020, don't know why